# Why Alan Guth limit inflaton field mechanism into range $10^{-35}$ to $10^{-34}$ seconds to justify an isotropy and homogeneity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmological-inflation

> The field, originally theorized by Alan Guth, provides a mechanism by which a period of rapid expansion from $10^{-35}$ to $10^{-34}$ seconds after the initial expansion can be generated, forming a universe consistent with observed spatial isotropy and homogeneity.

Ok.. but

1. Why limit inflaton field (a scalar field) is limited into a particular range domain $10^{-35}$ to $10^{-34}$?

This operation remember me a kind of integration/immersion

2. Why we need to observe physically a *universe consistent with observed spatial isotropy and homogeneity* ? 
   What is the real reason behind this mathematical model construction ?
3. But if we extend hypothetically this range from $10^{-35}$ to $10^{-12}$ Can we say that at the moment the expansion does not happen with isotropy and homogeneity ?